# Accessing keys when loading from JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am new to Python and I can not seem to find a solution that I understand.
• When I load in the JSON file I can print out the list as a whole; but if I try to access the key I get KeyError.
• Am I right in saying that Python converts the JSON file into a Python dictionary?
• Also, how would I go about accessing keys and then checking against them?

### Main Code:

[image: Main code]

### JSON File:

[image: JSON file]

### Console Error:

[image: Console error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JSON you have:

```
{
   "credentials": [
       {
         "username": "Admin",
         "password": "Password"
       }
   ]
}
```

### When Converted to the dictionary:

```
{'credentials': [{'username': 'Admin', 'password': 'Password'}]}
```

### Understanding the output of credentials:

```
print(data["credentials"])

# Output: 
[{'username': 'Admin', 'password': 'Password'}] 
# Do observe that the output is in a list format.

# For better understanding let's assume there is more than 1 credential:
[
 {'username': 'Admin', 'password': 'Password'},   # 0 of list
 {'username': 'Admin1', 'password': 'Password1'}  # 1 of list 
]
```

### Understanding the mistake:

```
# Instead of
data["username"]

# do
data["credentials"][0]["username"]
```

### The Right way:

```
for i in len(data["credentials"]):
    print("The username is ", data["credentials"][i]["username"])
```

Also, I encourage you to go through [Python Tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/python/) before working on something.
Python is widely considered among the easiest programming languages for beginners to learn.